# #NA error in vlooup with another workbook

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to retrieve the value of column 2 in x workbook on the basis of 20700 so if I directly give lookup value, formula is working fine but if I replace my lookup value with the range like A2[having the 20700 in A column] so It gives me N/A error.

VLOOKUP(20700,'[X.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)- working fine
VLOOKUP(K2,'[X.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0) - gives error

Kindly suggest me what to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teylyn hit the spot, but in case you can't change k2 for whatever reason, perhaps you could use one of the following to solve your issue.

```
VLOOKUP(value(K2),'[X.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)
VLOOKUP(trim(K2),'[X.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)
VLOOKUP(clean(K2),'[X.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When Vlookup returns #N/A that means that the lookup value is not found in the first column of the lookup table.

Reasons can be that numbers are stored as text (they look the same, but they are different data types), or leading/trailing spaces, or the numbers have decimals but have been formatted not to show decimals.

If you can type `20700` into the formula and get a result, but plugging in `K2` fails, chances are that K2 does NOT contain the NUMBER 20700, but something that just looks like it.

Use a formula like `=K2=20700` and if that returns FALSE, it proves my case.

I suggest you check your data for such inconsistencies and clean it up.